# Move *.wav files to new sub folder in multiple folders

Tags: windows-7, script, file-management

On my Windows 7 x64 system, I have in my music folder both *.mp3 and *.wav files in a directory structure similar to this:

```
D:\users\username\Music\Music\Artist\Album\musicfiles
```

I'd like to move all my wav files to a new sub folder similar to:

```
D:\users\username\Music\Music\Artist\Album\WAV\wavfiles
```

creating the new "WAV" subfolder in each "Album" folder as the command or batch file processes them.

I have seen several similar questions but nothing quite like this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: eh. This looks like a bit of a pain to do. Do the wav files have any sort of tagging ? I've tried and failed with two approaches already.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood something, running the following command from a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7) should do what you need: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %G in (\`dir "D:\users\username\Music\*.wav" /b /s\`) do @md "%~dpG\WAV\wavfiles" 2>nul & @move "%~G" "%~dpG\WAV\wavfiles" >nul`

Comment: I tried that FOR command and get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." I should mention in my examples "musicfiles" and "wavefiles" were wildcards.  Musicfiles = *.mp3 & *.wav and "wavefiles" just means *.wav.  So my current directory structure is D:\users\username\Music\Music\Artist\Album\*.mp3 & *.wav. Where I want to get to is: for the mp3 files: "D:\Users\username\Music\Music\Artist\Album\*.mp3 and for the wav files: "D:\Users\username\Music\Music\Artist\Album\WAV\*.wav.  Also, "Artist" & "Album" are wildcards too; they change as the Artist and Album do.

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing a search on the parent directory, include all sub-directories.  Then just choose the files in the search window and then move or copy them into the directory you want them in.

Comment: I have 10,199 files in 1,693 directories.  Creating new WAV folders in all my Album folders and then moving the wav files there would take days, if not months.  But I appreciate the suggestion.  I certainly didn't specify, and you had no way of knowing.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!  I did "dir d:\users\username\music\music*. /b /s > music_folders.txt" to capture the folder names.  I opened music_folders.txt in Excel, appended "\WAV" to each folder, and saved it to another text file named music_wav_folders.txt.  Then opened it and deleted the folders that did not contain any music files.  Then ran:
for /f "delims=" %G in (Music_wav_files.txt) do (md "%~G")
to create the directories and then:
for /f "delims=" %G in (music_folders.txt) do (move "%~G*.wav" "%~G\WAV")
to move the wav files to the new WAV subfolders.  Yippie!